# Need alternate to reversed(), or perhaps another indexing error

Tags: python, python-2.7

This program is going through a web-based development environment and is actually my attempt to get what I need from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) that I can't actually import in this case. I've changed the function somewhat to meet the naming requirements, but it should be basically the same. My current problem is that reversed() is not implemented, so I have to work around that. I tried creating a list with a for loop that iterated down, both inside and outside of this function. I also tried the current version without the ()s around it. Now I get an error that I'm out of range of the index when I run this. What are my alternatives to reversed?

```
def combinations_of_options(options, opt_len):
    ''' yields all combinations of option in specific length
    '''
    pool = tuple(options)
    pool_len = len(pool)
    if opt_len > pool_len:
        return
    indices = range(opt_len)
    yield tuple(pool[index] for index in indices)
    while True:
        for index in (range(opt_len,-1,-1)): #this is the line that uses reversed
            if indices[index] != index + pool_len - opt_len:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[index] += 1
        for dummy_index in range(index+1, opt_len):
            indices[dummy_index] = indices[dummy_index-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[index] for index in indices)
```

Comment: The easy answer is to use `opt_len-1` in your `range`. Remember that if the range were going forward, that would be the last value emitted.

Comment: Thank you! I had played with that previously, in other attempts at fixing this problem!